# MySQL Invalid default value for <column>

Tags: mysql, default

When I execute this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE MG_FOLDER (
  UUID CHAR(24) NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR(100),
  OWNER VARCHAR(32),
  CREATED TIMESTAMP,
  MODIFIED TIMESTAMP,
  ARCH BOOLEAN,
  FOLDER_UUID CHAR(24),
  SERIAL INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT FOLDER_PK PRIMARY KEY(UUID)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

I get this error:

```
Invalid default value for 'MODIFIED'
```

I don't think I'm setting a default value for `MODIFIED`, so what is causing the problem?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3130 (able to build schema without errors)

Answer (score 0):

You need specify  in `COLUMNS TIMESTAMP`  any with `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), or NOW()` and other with `DEFAULT NULL` or both with default null, but is necesary specify...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MG_FOLDER` (
  `UUID` char(24) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `OWNER` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATED` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `MODIFIED` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `ARCH` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FOLDER_UUID` char(24) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `SERIAL` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UUID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```